# Access List items type of a class

Tags: c#, list

I have a class that describes a persons firstname and lastname like this :

```
public class Person
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
}
```

And a list in which i add a `Person` item like this :

```
List<Person> PersonList;
```

I fill the List after using Xml Serialization. When I check the list capacity everything seems to be ok.

My question is , how can I access a persons firstname or lastname from the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your properties on `Person` are implicitly private because you didn't provide an access modifier. Let's fix that:

```
public class Person { 
    public string firstname;
    public string lastname;
}
```

Then, you need to index into an element in the list, and then you can access specific properties on a specific element of the list;

```
int index = // some index
// now, PersonList[index] is a Person
// and we can access its accessible properties
Console.WriteLine(PersonList[index].firstname);
```

Of course, you have to make sure that `index` is a valid `index` in your list, that is, it satifies `0 <= index < PersonList.Count`.